# Opening pdf files with dates through a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Every day I have a new subfolder named after today and i need to open couple pdfs in that folder ending in the exact same date. How would i go about doing this in a batch file?

For example:

```
C:\Users\fakename\0925\a0925.pdf

C:\Users\fakename\0925\b0925.pdf

C:\Users\fakename\0925\c0925.pdf
```

keep in mind tomorrow will look like

```
C:\Users\fakename\0926\a0926.pdf

C:\Users\fakename\0926\b0926.pdf

C:\Users\fakename\0926\c0926.pdf
```

how do i make a batch file to open those files every time without going in and changing anything? Is it possible through .bat? I know its possible through excel VBA. Thanks

I basically want it to do this

start /max C:\Users\fakename\0925\a0925.pdf

start /max C:\Users\fakename\0925\b0925.pdf

start /max C:\Users\fakename\0925\c0925.pdf

I can write the specific date in and it will open the files, but I want to make it so I don't have to go into the file everyday and change the date to today. I want it to look up todays date based on mmdd format and open it. I'm sorry I don't know much batch coding.

The pdf basically look like this everyday, the only thing that changes is the date (0925)

5010aaa0925

5010bbb0925

5010ccc0925

then tomorrow the files will look like

5010aaa0926

5010bbb0926

5010ccc0926

the file will always start with 5010 followed by the name. 5010aaa, 5010bbb, 5010ccc

Comment: Please share your code and initial effort, so others can help you with more specific issues.

Comment: Do the files really have `a` `b` and `c` as prefixes?  Are these prefixes always the same?

Comment: yes there is always the exact 7 letter prefix before the date that always stay the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

start "" /max "C:\Users\fakename\%mm%%dd%\a%mm%%dd%.pdf"
start "" /max "C:\Users\fakename\%mm%%dd%\b%mm%%dd%.pdf"
start "" /max "C:\Users\fakename\%mm%%dd%\c%mm%%dd%.pdf"

pause
```

Comment: Sorry I have one more question, Lets say I have a file named "apple", it has no extension but I need the file to open in notepad. As of now it starts the file, but pops up the box to open the file as, is there a way to skip this and open directly as a .txt but at the same time keeping the extension at nothing

Comment: Open a new question for another topic - they are free. :)